# how to know the default time for xmlrpc timeout

Tags: python, ubuntu, rpc, xml-rpc, freeswitch

I am facing an issue with rpc timeout for that need to know the default time for xmlrpc timeout.

while my app is connected with freeswitch calls are going but facing rpc timeout issue

How can I specify a default timeout for an xmlrpc config file

Comment: I'm guessing you're asking about timeouts, and changed the question accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.